# Set matplotlib plot axis to be the dataframe column name

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like so:

```
data = DataFrame({'Sbet': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Length' : [2,4,6,8,10])
```

Then I have a function that plots and fits this data

```
def lingregress(x,y):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
    r_sq = r_value ** 2

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,intercept + slope * x,c='r')

    print 'The slope is %.2f with R squared of %.2f' % (slope, r_sq)
```

Then I would call the function on the dataframe:

```
 linregress(data['Sbet'],data['Length'])
```

My question is how do I get the x axis label and y axis label to be `Sbet` and `Length` within the function as well as the plot title to be `Sbet vs Length`  I've tried a few things but I tend to get the whole column back when I use `plt.xlabel(data['Sbet'])` and `plt.title`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ordered columns

Build your dataframe with the columns in a defined order:

```
data = DataFrame.from_items([('Sbet', [1,2,3,4,5]), ('Length', [2,4,6,8,10])])
```

Now you can use the first column as `x` and the second column as `y`:

```
def lingregress(data):
    x_name = data.columns[0]
    y_name = data.columns[1]
    x = data[x_name]
    y = data[y_name]
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
    r_sq = r_value ** 2

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.xlabel(x_name)
    plt.ylabel(y_name)
    plt.title('{x_name} vs. {y_name}'.format(x_name=x_name, y_name=y_name))
    plt.plot(x,intercept + slope * x,c='r')

    print('The slope is %.2f with R squared of %.2f' % (slope, r_sq))


lingregress(data)
```

### Explicit column names

Dictionaries have not useful order. Therefore, you don't know the column order and you need to supply the order of names explicitly.

This would work:

```
def lingregress(data, x_name, y_name):
    x = data[x_name]
    y = data[y_name]
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
    r_sq = r_value ** 2

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.xlabel(x_name)
    plt.ylabel(y_name)
    plt.title('{x_name} vs. {y_name}'.format(x_name=x_name, y_name=y_name))
    plt.plot(x,intercept + slope * x,c='r')

    print('The slope is %.2f with R squared of %.2f' % (slope, r_sq))


lingregress(data, 'Sbet', 'Length')
```

[image]

Comment: That is a lot of manual/explicit work. Imagine with many column names .. There really is no more intelligent / automated inference way to link a column of names in a df to matplotlib?