# Infer Series Labels and Data from pandas dataframe column for plotting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Consider a simple 2x2 dataset with with Series labels prepended as the first column ("Repo")

```
            Repo AllTests Restricted
0      Galactian   1860.0      410.0
1  Forecast-MLib    140.0       47.0
```

Here are the DataFrame columns:

```
p(df.columns)
([u'Repo', u'AllTests', u'Restricted']
```

So we have the first column is the string/label and the second and third columns are data values. We want one series per *row* corresponding to the `Galactian` and the `Forecast-MLlib` repos.

It would seem this would be a common task and there would be a straightforward way to simply `plot` the DataFrame .  However the following related question does not provide any simple way: it essentially throws away the DataFrame structural knowledge and plots manually: 
 [Set matplotlib plot axis to be the dataframe column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653259/set-matplotlib-plot-axis-to-be-the-dataframe-column-name)

So is there a more natural way to plot these Series - that does not involve deconstructing the already-useful DataFrame but instead infers the first column as labels and the remaining as series data points?

**Update** Here is a self contained snippet

```
runtimes = npa([1860.,410.,140.,47.])
runtimes.shape = (2,2)

labels = npa(['Galactian','Forecast-MLlib'])
labels.shape=(2,1)
rtlabels = np.concatenate((labels,runtimes),axis=1)
rtlabels.shape = (2,3)

colnames = ['Repo','AllTests','Restricted']
df = pd.DataFrame(rtlabels, columns=colnames)
ps(df)
df.set_index('Repo').astype(float).plot()
plt.show()
```

And here is output

```
             Repo AllTests Restricted
0       Galactian   1860.0      410.0
1  Forecast-MLlib    140.0       47.0
```

And with `piRSquared` help it looks like this

[image]
So the data is showing now .. but the Series and Labels are swapped. Will look further to try to line them up properly.

**Another update**

By `flipping the columns/labels` the series are coming out as desired.

The change was to :

```
labels = npa(['AllTests','Restricted'])
..
colnames = ['Repo','Galactian','Forecast-MLlib']
```

[image]

So the updated code is

```
runtimes = npa([1860.,410.,140.,47.])
runtimes.shape = (2,2)

labels = npa(['AllTests','Restricted'])
labels.shape=(2,1)
rtlabels = np.concatenate((labels,runtimes),axis=1)
rtlabels.shape = (2,3)

colnames = ['Repo','Galactian','Forecast-MLlib']
df = pd.DataFrame(rtlabels, columns=colnames)
ps(df)
df.set_index('Repo').astype(float).plot()
plt.title("Restricting Long-Running Tests\nin Galactus and Forecast-ML")
plt.show()

p('df columns', df.columns)
ps(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas assumes your label information is in the index and columns.  Set the index first:

```
df.set_index('Repo').astype(float).plot()
```

Or

```
df.set_index('Repo').T.astype(float).plot()
```

Comment: Thx! I am ending up with `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`.  If the second and third (numeric only) columns were converted using `df.astype(float)` then a plot appears .. but then without the labels/index.

Comment: @javadba put astype after set_index

Comment: Please see OP: your suggestion is helping now. I still have the Series and Labels inverted.

Comment: @javadba you could transpose as well